# Fixed-length time series difference measurement

Tags: time-series, similarities

I have a very specific case of time series comparison.

Suppose we have two time series $T_c$ and $T_s$, both of them $512$ discrete points in size. Both of them have been sampled at the same frequency and basically are representations of the same data source, before ($T_c$) and after ($T_s$) some specific treatment.

Currently, I am using the following list of measurements in evaluating the differences between $T_c$ and $T_s$:

- Discrete values of the measured quantity at specific ordinates;
- Maximum and minimum values of the measured quantity;
- RMSE and absolute difference in specific ordinate regions;
- Derivative maximum and averaged values;
- Cross-correlation function value;

The questions are:

1. What could be a more *generic* approach to measurement of the effect of the aforementioned treatment on the data source?
2. Following from the nature of the data it represents, $T_c$ has a distinctive shape (e.g., regions of positive and negative slope). How can I use this knowledge? What could be a more *specific* approach to measurement of the effect of the treatment, considering the known properties of the $T_c$ series?

Comment: What kind of regression model you are planning to  use ?

Comment: I don't really think that any sort of regression analysis is applicable to my problem (please, correct me if I'm wrong). To clarify, my intention is to determine the cluster of measurements that have to be performed on the described series, which would quantitatively indicate the application of the special treatment to the data source through going over (or under) the certain threshold value. The threshold values themselves are going to be determined further using SVM. Thank you for your interest in my question!

Comment: just asked for my own proposes. I think that's a really good question.